# I want to pass multiple variables from PHP to python

Tags: python, php, html

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <head>
         <title>HTML Forms</title>
      </head>
      <p>Add your details:</p>
      <form name="form" method="get">
         Number 1:<br> <input type="number" name="first">
         <br>
         Number 2:<br> <input type="number" name="second">
         <br>
         Number 3:<br> <input type="number" name="third">
         <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

```php
<?php
$var1 =  $_GET['first'];
$var2 =  $_GET['second'];
$var3 =  $_GET['third'];
$command = escapeshellcmd("python total.py $var1 $var2 $var3");
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo ($output);

?>
```

```py
import sys

num_1 = sys.argv[1]

num_2 = sys.argv[2]

num_3 = sys.argv[3]

print("total:", num_1+num_2+num_3)
```

I have shared the code I am using. I want to get the values from user using the HTML code and read it using PHP. Then pass the values from PHP script to python script, do the task and display the output.

For some reason I am unable to do that. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your header manually and set column names when you read the csv file:

```
with open('data2.csv') as fp:
    header = fp.readline().split()
    cols = [c for i, c in enumerate(header[1:]) if c != header[i-1]]
    df = pd.read_csv(fp, header=None, names=cols, sep='\s+', engine='python')
```